# could i substitute mushrooms for pork/chicken in a dumpling recipe?

Tags: substitutions, asian-cuisine, vegetarian, mushrooms, dumplings

i would like to try making some vegetable dumplings as i thought it would be a tasty way to get some more veggies in, and i like mushrooms. could i substitue some finely chopped or minced mushrooms + a bit of oil (to help with lack of fat from the meat, i do this with leaner mince sometimes) in my recipe? current filling recipe fills about 100 wrappers, i usually make a half batch. this is the recipe:

  1/2 head cabbage

  500g pork or chicken mince

  0.5 red onion

  1 cup spring onion

  1 grated carrot

  3 tbsp soy sauce

  2 tbsp minced ginger

  2 tbsp sesame oil

  2 eggs

  cornstarch

  some other spices depending on my mood

would this substitution work? i dont care about lack of protien.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider that mushrooms are mostly water, in any case significantly “wetter” than your mince.

A standard procedure to deal with the issue is to cook (or fry) the chopped mushrooms separately on high heat until a lot of water has evaporated. This has the nice side effect of concentrating the mushroom flavor, bringing out the “umami”.

Note that this step will mean you end up with less mushrooms, so you may want to start out with more and then measure the sautéed mushrooms for your filling.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. i will try this next week once our current batch in the freezer has been used up. thanks!

Comment: Cabbage and onions both have a lot of water in them; could you perhaps use *dried* mushrooms at this stage?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use mushrooms. I would slice and sauté them to allow the water to evaporate, let them brown nicely to get that savory umami taste.